# How can I add hoverMessage for my decoration before/after in vscode extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I added a decoration and set before to my vscode extension.

```
const decoration: vscode.DecorationOptions = {
        range: new vscode.Range(startPos.line, startPos.character, endPos.line, endPos.character),
        hoverMessage,
        renderOptions: {
            before: {
                contentIconPath: vscode.Uri.parse(decorationBase64Result.base64),
                height: vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('editor').get('fontSize')
            },
        },
};
```

And I want to add hoverMessage to this before, but I found the doc only has the hoverMessage to decoration itself.

I want to set the hoverMessage for the before but not the code in range, like Gitlens. How can I do this?

Comment: write a `HoverProvider`

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks your reply. I have noticed this API, but I noticed the HoverProvider also need to provide the position. But the decoration before is not taking up any range.

Comment: if GitLens does what you want you can look at the source code, it has to use the same API as you

Comment: @rioV8 I have check the gitlens's source code. They did not used the HoverProvider and DecorationOptions.hoverMessage. But unfortunately, I cannot find the API where they called to realize this effect.